How to run OPL model in python parallelly
I am currently developing a Python script that sequentially solves an OPL model for each scenario sequentially. The python code is given below:
from doopl.factory import create_opl_model
import pandas as pd

# PHA Parameters
N_s = 3  # Number of scenarios
z_kbs = []  # List to store z_kb results for each scenario
x_ks = []   # List to store x_k results for each scenario

nodes_sets = [
[(9,), (18,), (26,), (28,)],
[(5,), (6,), (7,), (12,), (32)],
[(8,), (19,), (23,),]
]

# Path to your OPL model file
model_path = "C:/Users/user/opl/Planning/Planning.mod"

def solve_subproblem(nodes):
 with create_opl_model(model=model_path) as opl:
    opl.set_input('line_Node',nodes)

    opl.run()

    # Extract the decision variables z_kb and x_k from the OPL solution
    z_kb = []
    x_k = []

    # Extracting the solutions from the OPL output
    for name, table in opl.report.items():
        if 'solutions_1' in name:  # Ensure this matches the set name in OPL
            for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
                z_kb.append(t[1])  # Adjust to the actual position/index of z_kb
        elif 'solutions_2' in name:  # Ensure this matches the set name in OPL
            for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
                x_k.append(t[1])  # Adjust to the actual position/index of x_k
    
    return z_kb, x_k

# Step 2: Solve the initial subproblems for each scenario
for s in range(N_s):
z_kb_scenario, x_k_scenario =solve_subproblem(nodes_sets[s])

# Append the results for each scenario as a new sublist
z_kbs.append(z_kb_scenario)  # Add results of z_kb for scenario `s` to the list
x_ks.append(x_k_scenario)    # Add results of x_k for scenario `s` to the list

I would like to run the OPL model in parallel for all scenarios to speed up the solution process. Could you please suggest how to implement this in Python to ensure that each scenario is processed concurrently?

You can change this part:
# Step 2: Solve the initial subproblems for each scenario
for s in range(N_s):
z_kb_scenario, x_k_scenario =solve_subproblem(nodes_sets[s])

using Python concurrent:
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_s) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(solve_subproblem, nodes) for nodes in nodes_sets]
    for future in futures:
        z_kb_scenario, x_k_scenario = future.result()

Remember to add at the beginning: from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

Does parallel computation rely on the number of cores in the system? The parameter max_workers is typically set to the number of available cores (max_workers=cores) to reduce the computation time

Parallel computation usually relies on the number of cores. max_workers is set to available cores for efficient processing, but optimal worker count varies based on tasks and system workload. Sometimes setting slightly fewer workers can improve performance.
